# Very slow query when using `id in (max(id))` in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We recently moved our database from MariaDB to AWS Amazon Aurora RDS (MySQL). We observed something strange in a set of queries. We have two queries that are very quick, but when together as nested subquery it takes ages to finish.

Here `id` is the primary key of the table

```sql
SELECT * FROM users where id in(SELECT max(id) FROM users where id = 1);
```

execution time is ~350ms
[image]

```sql
SELECT * FROM users where id in(SELECT id FROM users where id = 1);
```

execution time is ~130ms
[image]

```sql
SELECT max(id) FROM users where id = 1;
```

execution time is ~130ms

```sql
SELECT id FROM users where id = 1;
```

execution time is ~130ms

We believe it has to do something with the type of value returned by `max` that is causing the indexing to be ignored when running the outer query from results of the sub query.

All the above queries are simplified for illustration of the problem. The original queries have more clauses as well as 100s of millions of rows. The issue did not exist prior to the migration and worked fine in MariaDB.

--- RESULTS FROM MariaDB ---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL seems to optimize less efficient compared to MariaDB (int this case).

When doing this in MySQL (see: [DBFIDDLE1](https://dbfiddle.uk/3QzpVill)), the execution plans look like:

- For the query without `MAX`:

| id select_type table partitions type | possible_keys | key key_len ref | rows | filtered Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 SIMPLE integers null const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY 4 const | 1 | 100.00 Using index |
| 1 SIMPLE integers null const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY 4 const | 1 | 100.00 Using index |

- For the query with `MAX`:

| id select_type table partitions type | possible_keys | key key_len ref | rows | filtered Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 PRIMARY integers null index null | PRIMARY | 4 null | 1000 | 100.00 Using where; Using index |
| 2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY null null null null | null | null null | null | null Select tables optimized away |

While MariaDB (see: [DBFIDDLE2](https://dbfiddle.uk/8761QCDS) does have a better looking plan when using MAX:

| id select_type table type | possible_keys | key key_len ref | rows | filtered Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 PRIMARY system null | null | null null | 1 | 100.00 |
| 1 PRIMARY integers const PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 const | 1 | 100.00 Using index |
| 2 MATERIALIZED null null null | null | null null | null | null Select tables optimized away |

EDIT: Because of time (some lack of it ) I now add some info

1. A suggestion to fix this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM integers
WHERE i IN (select * from (SELECT MAX(i) FROM integers WHERE i=1)x);
```

When looking at the EXECUTION PLAN from MariaDB, which has 1 extra step, I tried to do the same in MySQL. Above query has an even bigger execution plan, but tests show that it performs better. (for explain plans, see: [DBFIDDLE1a](https://dbfiddle.uk/WMdGhWV2))

2. "the question is Mariadb that much faster? it uses a step more that mysql"

One step more does not mean that things get slower.

MySQL takes about 2-3 seconds on the query using the MAX, and MariaDB does execute the same in under 10 msecs. But this is performance, and time may vary on different systems.

Comment: Thanks Luuk for confirmation and the fiddle. How do you suggest fixing this? I understand changing the subquery to a `join` would fix it. Is there a way to configure MySQL to work like MariaDB? I may not be able to make all the changes to all such queries in the time we have.

Comment: the question is Mariadb that much faster? it uses a step more that mysql

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT max(id) FROM users where id = 1
```

Is strange.  Since it is looking only at rows where id = 1, then "max" is obviously "1".  So is the min.  And the average.\

Perhaps you wanted:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM users
```

Is there an index on `id`?  Perhaps the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If not, then that might explain the sluggishness.

This can be done much faster (against assuming an index):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Does that give you what you want?

To discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`